# Restrict web tools access in OFbiz

Tags: security, ofbiz

Currently my web tools front end is running in OFBiz and is accessible from the whole wide world (www) just like the ecommerce store. 
I don’t like that a bit. Although it is protected by strong password.

Can I restrict that app access to certain IP addresses or from local host only?

It would be best if that application can run on different port altogether or listening on 127.0.0.1 interface only. Or both :)

Any experience with this, please?

Kind Regards,
Boris

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Ofbiz and working within (mostly) the opentaps context. From what I see I'm not sure you can achieve this but perhaps it's possible to change the mount-point of the webapp for added security such that it's not obviously accesible through the default OOTB name.
I'll reply later on in the future when I have looked into this myself. +1 for the question btw.